# $http promise not updating scope (ng-hide)

Tags: javascript, angularjs

What I am trying to achieve here is sending a get request to my api, which responds with a true / false depending on whether the user is logged in or not. ideally I want to hide the login form if the user is logged in. I am using angular's built in http method, which returns a promise and from what I understand is already wrapped in $apply, so I would have thought that the scope would have been updated automatically.

My controller:

```
.controller('MyCtrl1', ['$scope', 'isLoggedIn', '$timeout', function($scope, isLoggedIn, $timeout) {

        isLoggedIn.getState().then(function(result) {   
            $scope.displayLogin = result.data.state;
        });

        $scope.getLoginState = function() {
             console.log($scope.displayLogin);
        }
}]);
```

My service:

```
.factory('isLoggedIn', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getState: function(scope) { 
            return $http.get('/login-state').then(function(result) {
                return result
            });
        }
    }
})
```

html:

```
  <form method="most" action="/login" ng-hide="displayLogin">
```

I know that the value itself is being updated because I have a button with ng click bound to the getLoginState method which returns displayLogin with the correct value, it seems ng-hide isn't reflecting this? as if the scope is not aware of the change.

How can I get this working, so that my truey value hides the form?

Comment: I can't see any more code. Don't know if the `form` is on `scope` or not of the `displayLogin` property.

Comment: [Offtopic] The then-callback in your isLoggedIn-Service returns to nowhere so it can be dropped to save cpu-time.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your code it seems you spec your factory to return the promise of `$http` service ?

```
.factory('isLoggedIn', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getState: function(scope) { 
            return $http.get('/login-state');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Although OP's code could be simplified into this, I think the effect of this is none to the issue he's describing

Comment: Antonio is right, i did however modify my code to this, for some reason I saw a lot of examples where the service was structures how i had it, not sure why though - i am new to angular so I just mimicked it (but yet, it had no real effect)

Answer (score 0):

I will try to make a plunker to check this, but if you instead of

```
isLoggedIn.getState().then(function(result) {   
    $scope.displayLogin = result.data.state;
});
```

Try to write

```
$scope.displayLogin = isLoggedIn.getState()
```

And modify your factory to return the result of the $http.get instead of the $http.get itself?

**Update:** Here is a version of your factory using a promise ($q service):

```
.factory('isLoggedIn', function($http, $q) {
    return {
        getState: function(cb) { 
          var deferred = $q.defer();
          $http.get("/login-state").success(function(data){
            deferred.resolve(data);
          });
          deferred.promise.then(function (result) {
            return cb(result);
          });
        }
    }
});
```

You then use it like this:

```
isLoggedIn.getState(function(returnData) {
    $scope.displayLogin = returnData;
});
```

I had to use a callback to get it to update properly. Your promise-object should be updated when you get the data. Here is a link to the plunker: http://plnkr.co/edit/c5YguV5PbE29ZLay3oI4?p=preview